# Apply Different Color for Different SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have some svg's I want to apply conditional for applying color, I written detailed in jsfiddle link

1. First SVG Can apply only Red / Green
2. Second SVG Can apply Blue / Orange
3. Third SVG Can apply Yellow / Pink

[http://jsfiddle.net/6w21z1bq/](https://jsfiddle.net/6w21z1bq/)

Comment: can you explain more what issue you face?

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check updated code on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/6w21z1bq/1/)
. have make change in SVG tags and apply data-index attribute to circles and buttons. if selected circle  dta-index attribut is same  as clicked button  data-index attribute then it will apply color else show alert.

```js
var clickedPath = '';
var rIndex = '';
$('#select1,#select2,#select3').on("click", function() {
    clickedPath = $(this);
    rIndex = $(this).attr('data-index');
    clickedPath.css({ stroke: "#00ff00" });
});
  
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
    var attr = '';
    attr = $(this).attr('data-index').split(',');
    if($.inArray(rIndex,attr) >= 0 ){
      clickedPath.css({ fill: $(this).attr('data-color') });
    }else{
      alert("Wrong click");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select SVG and Apply Color <br/>
 
 <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" id="select1" data-index = '1' />
  </svg>

  <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4" fill="red" id="select2" data-index = '2' />
  </svg>
  
  <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" fill="red" id="select3"  data-index = '3' />
  </svg>


<br/> <br/> 
 
  Apply to Only 1st SVG / For 2nd and 3rd should not be Apply, Alert Box Should Come
  
<button class="btn" id="btn-test1" data-color="#ff0000" data-index = '1,2'>Red</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test2" data-color="#00ff00" data-index = '1,2'>Green</button>

<br/> <br/> 

Apply to Only 2nd SVG / For 1st and 3rd should not be Apply, Apply Alert Box Should Come

<button class="btn" id="btn-test3" data-color="#0000ff" data-index = '2,3'>Blue</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test4" data-color="#ff9300" data-index = '2,3'>Orange</button>
 
<br/> <br/>

 Apply to Only 3rd SVG / For  3rd and 1st should not be Apply, Apply Alert Box Should Come

<button class="btn" id="btn-test5" data-color="#ffba00" data-index = '3,1'>Yellow</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test5" data-color="#ff006c" data-index = '3,1'>Pink</button>
```

Comment: @JavascriptGuy you can take any value. but then you need to change logic to compare index and other things

Comment: @JavascriptGuy  check my updated answer . i have added code snippet

Comment: @JavascriptGuy check my updated answer . i have added code snippet

Comment: Somehow not able to create fiddle ..but I have updated answer and added code snippets ...check

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this:

updated svg:

```
<button class="btn select1" id="btn-test1" data-color="#ff0000">Red</button>
<button class="btn select1" id="btn-test2" data-color="#00ff00">Green</button>

<button class="btn select2" id="btn-test3" data-color="#0000ff">Blue</button>
<button class="btn select2" id="btn-test4" data-color="#ff9300">Orange</button>

<button class="btn select3" id="btn-test5" data-color="#ffba00">Yellow</button>
<button class="btn select3" id="btn-test5" data-color="#ff006c">Pink</button>
```

What i updated above is just added a class names to the buttons as same as the ids of the svg like, if svg id is `id="select1"` then the corresponding buttons will have `class="btn select1"`.

and js code as updated:

```
var clickedPath = '';

$('#select1,#select2,#select3').on("click", function () {
    clickedPath = $(this);
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false); // enable all buttons
    $('.btn').not('.' + clickedPath.attr('id')).prop('disabled', true); // enable the corresponding buttons.
    clickedPath.css({
        stroke: "#00ff00"
    });
});

$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    clickedPath.css({
        fill: $(this).attr('data-color')
    });
});
```

```js
var clickedPath = '';

$('#select1,#select2,#select3').on("click", function() {
  clickedPath = $(this);
  $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
  $('.btn').not('.' + clickedPath.attr('id')).prop('disabled', true);
  clickedPath.css({
    stroke: "#00ff00"
  });
});

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  clickedPath.css({
    fill: $(this).attr('data-color')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select SVG and Apply Color
<br/>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" id="select1" />
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4" fill="red" id="select2" />
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" fill="red" id="select3" />
</svg>
<br clear='all'/>
<br/>Apply to Only 1st SVG / For 2nd and 3rd should not be Apply, Alert Box Should Come
<button class="btn select1" id="btn-test1" data-color="#ff0000">Red</button>
<button class="btn select1" id="btn-test2" data-color="#00ff00">Green</button>
<br/>
<br/>Apply to Only 2nd SVG / For 1st and 3rd should not be Apply, Apply Alert Box Should Come
<button class="btn select2" id="btn-test3" data-color="#0000ff">Blue</button>
<button class="btn select2" id="btn-test4" data-color="#ff9300">Orange</button>
<br/>
<br/>Apply to Only 3rd SVG / For 3rd and 1st should not be Apply, Apply Alert Box Should Come
<button class="btn select3" id="btn-test5" data-color="#ffba00">Yellow</button>
<button class="btn select3" id="btn-test5" data-color="#ff006c">Pink</button>
```